# What does NHibernateUtil.Initialize do?

Tags: nhibernate

I have inherited a piece of code which calls NHibernateUtil.Initialize.

I am relatively new to NHibernate and have not been able to work out specifically what calling NHibernateUtil.Initialize does.

What does it do and in what scenarios should it be called ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basicaly it will eagerly load the domain objects that are lazily loaded or proxied by nhibernate.

Have a look at this from the [NHibernate website - lazy-loading-eager-loading](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/lazy-loading-eager-loading.html)  the reference is in the bottom quarter of the article.